# Vue js reactivity issue when updating objects inside array used in v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects, vue.js

I have an application using vue.js. I generate a list of results using v-for in an array of objects.
when I update the object inside nth item in array, using underscore _.extend, the view of project does not update.
There is a solution for this problem at http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html which indicates to use _.extend like this:

```
this.results.displayed[key] = _.extend({}, this.results.displayed[key], detail.items);
```

but the problem is when I use extend like it said, it does not update the view.

Comment: There's not enough information to figure out what is wrong. Can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vue is unable to detect the change when you set a new item by array index. To get around this, you can use the `$set()` method that Vue adds to the array.

```
var newObject = _.extend({}, this.results.displayed[key], detail.items);
this.results.displayed.$set(key, newObject);
```

More info [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats).

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/0joa6gro/) demonstrating use of .$set

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem of items in v-for not updating, by making sure that the tag containing the v-for was wrapped by a  tag.

It had been wrapped in a v-ons-list. And I could imagine some people wrapping it in a div tag. This is a quick possibility to eliminate before trying all the other more complicated solutions out there.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I had the same problem and this solved it